# ElasticSearch - how to filter hate words / insults in search analyze

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I'm trying to configure a ElasticSearch 7.

I configured some stopwords, I thought it included those words too, but it doesn't seem to be the case...

What is the best practice ?

My current settings looks like :

```
'analysis' => [
    'filter' => [
        ...
        'english_stop' => [
            'type' => 'stop',
            'stopwords' => '_english_'
        ],
        'english_stemmer' => [
            'type' => 'stemmer',
            'language' => 'english'
        ],
        'english_possessive_stemmer' => [
            'type' => 'stemmer',
            'language' => 'possessive_english'
        ]
        ...
    ],
    'analyzer' => [
        'rebuilt_english' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
            'filter' => [
                ...
                'english_possessive_stemmer',
                'lowercase',
                'english_stop',
                'english_stemmer'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A) If you'd like to ELIMINATE results containing bad words — i.e. disregard them completely in the search response — you could add an [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html).

First create the index as you normally would:

```json
PUT dirty-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": { ... },
      "analyzer": { ... }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rebuilt_english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add one "safe" and one "unsafe" doc:

```json
POST dirty-index/_doc
{
  "content": "some regular text"
}

POST dirty-index/_doc
{
  "content": "some taboo text with bad words"
}
```

Save a [filtered](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html#add-alias-api-request-body) index alias, thus creating a safe-ish "view" of the original index:

```
PUT dirty-index/_alias/dirty-index-filtered
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "content": ["taboo"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`taboo` is just one of many bad words taken from: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/bad-words.txt](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebiglou/resources/bad-words.txt)

And voila — the alias only contains the "safe" doc. Verify via:

```json
GET dirty-index-filtered/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

#### B) If you'd like to CENSOR select terms *before* they're indexed, you could do so via an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html).

Store the pipeline:

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_data_cleanser
{
  "description": "Runs a doc thru a censoring replacer...",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def bad_words = ['taboo', 'damn'];  // list all of 'em
          def CENSORED = '*CENSORED*';
          def content_copy = ctx.content;
          
          for (word in bad_words) {
            if (content_copy.contains(word)) {
              content_copy = content_copy.replace(word, CENSORED)
            }
          }
          
          ctx.content = content_copy;
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then reference it as a URL param when indexing the docs:

```json
                     |
                     v________
POST dirty-index/_doc?pipeline=my_data_cleanser
{
  "content": "some text with damn bad words"
}
```

which'll result in:

```
some text with *CENSORED* bad words
```

#### C) If you'd like to catch & replace select words as part of the ANALYSIS step, you could use a [`pattern_replace` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html).

```json
PUT dirty-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "bad_word_replacer": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "((taboo)|(damn))",      <--- not sure how this'll scale to potentially hundreds of words
          "replacement": "*CENSORED*"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_english": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "bad_word_replacer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rebuilt_english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this'll only affect the *analyzed* fields, but **NOT** the *stored* values:

```json
POST dirty-index/_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token&format=yaml
{
  "field": "content",
  "text": ["some taboo text"]
}
```

The produced tokens would then be:

```yaml
tokens:
- token: "some"
- token: "*CENSORED*"
- token: "text"
```

but they wouldn't be of too much avail because, if I understood your use case correctly, you don't need to disable **searching** for hate words — you need to disable their **retrieval**?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, that's exactly it, I want to remove them from the input. So, I don't think I look in the right place, and it must be filtered before the search... Maybe with something like https://github.com/snipe/banbuilder or https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Profanity ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes -- if you **do have control** over the incoming docs, filter the profanity before it reaches ES. That's certainly the simplest approach :)